# Beginner fusion table query...two column location and st_distance

Tags: javascript, sql, select, google-fusion-tables

I'm altering a google example template to try to construct a query that finds the nearest location in the table to the user-entered city.  And in this example, I just want to output the lat and lon and probably the "id" of the nearest table location to the user-inputted city. First, I'm using my LATITUDE column as location because it's been geocoded in the table as a two-column location.  Strangely, when I alerted that variable, it only displays the latitude instead of the lat/lng coordinates. I thought since LATITUDE was acting as a two column location, it would return a lat/lng.

So when I run this simple query after pushing the "go" button after entering a city:

```
 var queryList = [];
              queryList.push("SELECT LATITUDE,LONGITUDE FROM ");
              queryList.push(tableid);
```

and then alert the values, in the popup window, it works fine: http://greenandtheblue.com/whentoplant/test_query_geocode.html, alerting a lat and lon from the table...what I hoped it would.

But when I try to use the st_distance, I don't get any suggestion that it's working.

```
queryList.push("ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(LATITUDE, LATLNG("+coordinate.lat()+","+coordinate.lng()+")) LIMIT 1");
```

http://greenandtheblue.com/whentoplant/test_query_geocode_notworking.html

I prefer this method of querying...seems simpler:

```
query: {
            select: 'LATITUDE',
            from: tableid
          },
```

but I gathered from the example that I needed to put the second query (acted on when I push go) in an array of sorts, which makes it a bit more complicated.

I hope this is a clear enough question.  Thanks for any help.

Shad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I make the query like this:

```
queryList.push("SELECT STATION,STATION_NAME,ELEVATION,LATITUDE FROM ");
queryList.push(tableid);
 //query seems to work when I comment out the line below.
 queryList.push("ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(LATITUDE, LATLNG("+coordinate.lat()+","+coordinate.lng()+")) LIMIT 1");
 var query = encodeURIComponent(queryList.join(' '));
 var gvizQuery = new google.visualization.Query(
    'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + query);

 gvizQuery.send(function(response) {
    var datatable = response.getDataTable();
    var header = 'No results';
    var content = 'Sorry, no store delivers here.';
    if (datatable && (datatable.getNumberOfRows() > 0)) {
       header = datatable.getValue(0, 0);
       content = datatable.getValue(0, 1)+"<br>Station:"+datatable.getValue(0,0)+"<br>Elevation:"+datatable.getValue(0,2);
    }
    infoWindow.setContent('<h3>' + header + '</h3>' +
       '<p>' + content + '</p>');
    infoWindow.setPosition(coordinate);
    infoWindow.open(map);
  });
```

It [works](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_geocode_notworking.html) for me.

changed:

```
var query = encodeURIComponent(queryList.join(''));  // empty string
```

to:

```
var query = encodeURIComponent(queryList.join(' ')); // single space
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  Works nicely.